# What is the correct, conventional name for a test written via BDD

Tags: automated-testing, unit-tests, bdd, integration-testing, tdd

If I have a class/object/component, and I test its API directly, in complete isolation, mocking/stubbing any complex parameters on which it depends, it's called a Unit Test.

If I have a whole application made up of classes/objects/components, a user interface, and all sorts, and I test its behaviour through a certain journey (with no parts being mocked/stubbed) it's called an End-to-end test.

If I implement a new feature, and I write a test which interacts with the highest level of the application which has an effect on that feature (and thus include multiple classes/objects/components, but not necessarily all of them, and *may* need to mock/stub some components)... **what name would *you* give to this type of test?** (I realise I am taking part in BDD/TDD, but what is the name of the type of test I have written?).

Behaviour test? Spec test? Integration test? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

Under most circumstances this would be considered an **integration** test, but what it actually gets called will depend on your environment. I've known environments that would consider the type of test you describe a **functional** test, others, if you were dealing primarily with an API regardless of what the back end of the API did would call it an **API test**

In my opinion the **most important** aspect of what you call the test is that **everyone you communicate with knows what you mean when you name that type of test**.

Answer (score 1):

It could be called a **Feature test** or a "**functionary test**" as well.

- **Feature**: a distinctive attribute or aspect of something.
- **Functionality**: the quality of being suited to serve a purpose well;
  practicality.

And as Kate pointed out, what do you name it is far less important than how everyone should agree to name it.